# How to use join to select many to many relationship model in ruby on rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My data model is fellows, the note and hashtag's relationship is many to many

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title
  attr_accessible :content
  attr_accessible :created_at
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  has_and_belongs_to_many :hashtags
end

class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :notes
end

class NoteHashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  t.belongs_to :note, index: true
  t.belongs_to :hashtag, index: true
end
```

I want to inquire the sql like:

```
 select Note.* from Note inner join NoteHashtag on Note.id=NoteHashtag.note inner join Hashtag on NoteHastag.hashtag=Hashtag.id where Hashtag.name="test"
```

How to convert the sql into the datamodel operation in ruby on rails4?

I try to use the:

```
@note=Note.joins(:hashtag).where(name: "test")
```

and the error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Association named 'hashtag' was not found on Note;perhaps you misspelled it?):
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `has_many :through` associations if you are going to explicitly define the join model `NoteHashtag`. If you delete that model, you can do `@notes=Note.joins(:hashtag).where(name: "test")` and ActiveRecord will generate the query you are expecting.

Otherwise you could do

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :note_hashtags
  has_many :hashtags, through: :note_hash_tags
end

class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end

class NoteHashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :note
end
```

Then `@notes = Note.joins(:note_hashtags).joins(:hash_tags).where(name: "test)` would work.

Note that both of these will return more than one `note`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get records from many to many relationship by doing this:-

```
@note = Note.joins(:hashtags).where('hashtags.name' => 'test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you address this relationship originating from the proper model? Define your models like this:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :note_hashtags
  has_many :hashtags, through: :note_hashtags
end

class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :note_hashtags
  has_many :notes through: :notes_hashtags
end

class NoteHashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :note
  belongs_to :hashtag
end
```

And then query like this:

`Hashtag.where(name: 'Test').notes`